# Get an information about all connected devices in the WIFI - connection

Tags: android, device, network-scan

I'm going to create a app that analyze the current connected wifi-network.
Instead of that i want to get a number of all devices that are connected in that network im connected with my android mobile as well.

A possibility is to ping all possibils ips in my networt, but if im in a class "a" net i have to check over 17 mio of ips out, which would take to much time...

i.e. An Information: In the Textbox at the router 192.168.2.1 are 20 devices connected

Comment: How do you intend to send ICMP/Ping packets in Android?

Comment: I do it with Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); and then with his exec method... what i want was to get a solution that is faster then to ping all possible ips in my network. At least i ping the broadcast...